# How to write non brittle tests for knex (with mock-knex)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, knex.js

Well I use `knex` as library for database access and use `mock-knex` to assist for mocking (though this is up for debate). Testing is done wit jest.

To prevent an XY problem the function I try to (ultimately) test is:

```
export async function dbCreateSheet(user: number, match: number) {
    const scoring_db = dbDict('scoring');
    await scoring_db.insert({
        user: user,
        match: match,
    }).into("sheets");
}
```

However for simplicity I moved everything to a neat test:

```
import knexBuilder = require("knex");
import mockDb = require("mock-knex");

it("should create a sheet with ids given", async function() {
    const uId = 1;
    const matchId = 2;
    const tracker = mockDb.getTracker();
    const scoring_db = knexBuilder({
        client: 'pg',
    });
    mockDb.mock(scoring_db);
    tracker.on('query', (query: QueryDetails) => {
        console.log(query)
        expect(query.method).toEqual("insert");
        expect(query.bindings).toEqual([matchId, uId]);
        query.response([]);
    });
    tracker.install();
    await scoring_db.insert({
        user: uId,
        match: matchId,
    }).into("sheets")
    //await dbCreateSheet(uId, matchId);

    // IDEALLY: const result = await scoring_db.select('*').from("sheets");
    // and analyze the result object to "have" the new entry

})
```

I notice immediately: these tests are very very brittle. Not I am looking into the specification of knex to notice in which order the arguments are given. And further testing the "into" is even near impossible. Or I have to verify the actual nativeSQL.

And more importantly: it requires me to actually know the exact *order* of functions being called by the function `dbCreateSheet` - while decently logical here more complex things might do quite some complex queries and sometimes opt for multiple queries instead of a single.

Any change to any library (knex, driver, mock) could break this test, without breaking the code.

Is there a better way to test such a function? A function that just "inserts values into a database"?

Ideally it would just create a database in memory on the fly. As the "effect" of this function is that I could test against existence. (And the "logic" is that it selects the correct table and inserts the right values).

---

EDIT: to show the actual "visible mutation" a second function is part of this:

```
export async function dbGetSheets(user: number) {
    const scoring_db = dbDict('scoring');
    return await scoring_db.select().from("sheets").where({user: user});
}
```

The important bit to test is that something inserted through `dbCreateSheet` can be retrieved through `dbGetSheets`. How this happens are implementation details.

Comment: So... what is it that you are actually trying to test there? Making sure that `knex`'s insert and into methods are called when your `dbCreateSheet` function executes? Why couldn't you use just some generic mock implementation for that? I mean some very simple mock or stub, which supports builder pattern so that you can check what knex APIs has been called. Though IMO in most of the cases that kind of tests are waste of time (as you said it is up to debate).

Comment: @MikaelLepistö well not that knex is called, maybe in the future we would go for a different query-builder. But rather that "something" is making sure "somewhere" data is stored that can be retrieved by providing a user id. On user level it doesn't matter whether that's through sql, ini files or just the filesystem... And since unit tests run at userland, I shouldn't care there either?

Comment: from that answer I still couldn't understand what are you trying to achieve with that test. If you are trying to make sure that something is stored/retrieved from DB library APIs then you need to change test anyways if you change the library. If you want to abstract the whole DB API layer away (knex, filesystem, whatnot,...), then you need to create your own abstraction API and mock it instead from the rest of the application. Of course to unit test your abstraction API you will need to mock or something the underlying driver API like you are trying to do here...

Comment: You need to decide what level you are testing... if you are trying to test that your logic inside your own database abstraction is working as expected, then you cannot ignore the underlying database library API that you are using.